# How to Pass Selected Values in Multi-Value parameters to a subreport in SSRS 20008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my outer report, the one that the user runs, I just have a list with only 1 thing inside: a subreport.

The subreport takes a UserId and calculates a few stats using 4 different tablixes and datasets.

What I want the outer report to do is present the user with a list of UserIds as a multivalue parameter, and pass the selected values to the subreport.

However, what is doing is to pass ALL possible values to the subreport resulting in long delays, hundreds of pages and unwanted data.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set a filter of the values in the dataset that pulls all UserIds to be `IN` the paramter with the user selection.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one issue is the `userid` parameter has default values from the initial setup/query automatically setting the `userid` to all possibilities?

Also, the sub report should also have the same parameter as the outer one. Ensure this is also a multi-select but hidden and has no default values.

Then on the sub report properties you can set the `userid` parameter property to the main one.